# Get module import error when already imported while doing big query

Tags: google-bigquery

Running this in local host in anaconda jypter:
Wonder why it complains on 'db-dtypes' package when it is already there. Something to do with versions?  or something incorrect with query?

[Python code failing added image sincepage was complaining somehow on indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDpwe.png)

### Error i get is :

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery_pandas_helpers.py:42
41 try:
---> 42     import db_dtypes  # type: ignore
44     date_dtype_name = db_dtypes.DateDtype.name

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db_dtypes'
ValueError: Please install the 'db-dtypes' package to use this function.

while it is already there :
!pip install db-dtypes
!pip install db-dtypes
Requirement already satisfied: db-dtypes in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow>=3.0.0 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from db-dtypes) (12.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.2 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from db-dtypes) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=17.0 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from db-dtypes) (22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.6 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from db-dtypes) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.24.2->db-dtypes) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.24.2->db-dtypes) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\amita\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=0.24.2->db-dtypes) (1.16.0)